# Find Q-Point for a Transistor Circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8WY4T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am studying for an exam, and was given this problem to practice. I have finished a good portion of it, but run into some issues that make me question if I've made a mistake.

**Question**:
Find the Q-Point of the circuit (above). 
$$K_n = 1 {mA}/{V^2} $$  $$V_{tn} = 2 V$$

My Work:

$$Q-Point = (I_{D}, V_{DS}, V_{GS})$$

$$ I_{D} = K_n(V_{GS} - V_{TN})^2$$
$$V_{GS} = V_g - I_dR_s$$
$$V_g = V_{DD}*(R_2)/(R_1+R_2) = 20/4 = 5 V$$
$$V_{GS} = 5-2700I_D$$
$$I_{D} = .001(5-2700I_D - 2)^2$$
$$I_{D} = .001(7290000I_D^2 - 16200I_D + 9)$$
After troubling with the algebra...

Id = 1.57 mA or .783 mA

Thus:

Vgs = .761 V or 2.9 V

This is where I'm confused - why do I have two answers for Id and Vgs?

Comment: Connect your battery correctly.

Comment: @Autistic Didn't notice that - Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: You have two answers because you solved a quadratic equation. You will have to pick the one that makes more sense. I would focus on the options for Vgs. Once you have picked one of those you can figure out which Id matches that. I don't have the wherewithal to check your math, so I will let somebody else do that in a real answer.

Comment: Combine the 2 solutions you got for Vgs with the potential on the gate which will be 1/4 * 20 V, then you get two possible solutions for the voltage across Rs, since you know Id, you can determine which Vgs is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First use **0.783 mA** and find **Vgs**

**Vgs = 5 - 0.783*2.7 = 2.8859V**

Next we we find Vgs for Id = 1.57mA

**Vgs = 5 - 1.57*2.7 = 0.761V**

As you can see only Vgs = 2.886V and Id = 0.783mA is valid because Vgs cannot be lower than Vt. For Vgs < Vt the MOSFET is in cut-off region.

So the next time try to solve for Vgs directly

$$ I_{D} = K_n(V_{GS} - V_{TN})^2$$
$$ I_{D} = \frac{V_g - V_{GS}}{Rs}$$ 
$$ \frac{V_g - V_{GS}}{Rs}= K_n(V_{GS} - V_{TN})^2$$
$$ \frac{5V - V_{GS}}{2.7k\Omega}=1 {mA}/{V^2}(V_{GS} - 2V)^2$$

And the solution is

$$V_{GS}=0.744579V ;V_{GS}=2.88505V$$

As for this **Id = 1.11mA** let as see what we get

Vgs = 5-1.11*2.7 = 2.003V so for sure this is not the valid answer.

Comment: G36, you are right. I have made a simple (catastrophic) calculation error. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No - I do not think that it is possible to get two real and positive solutions.
Rather I think, you have made an error solving the quadratic equation. Here is my result: **Id=1.11mA.**

Comment: Sorry, my above calculation was not correct.